# a good way to implent l.php like facebook?

Tags: php, design-patterns

what is the l.php

> im guessing l.php is link.php on
>   facebook. its a pre-redirecting
>   script. every link on facebook is
>   filtered to link.php?to=link

i have some things in mind. like

1. make a render class or filter the input with regex, finds an *www.link.com* then change it to something like `<a href="http://www.oursite.php?to=www.link.com">link</a>` , the problem is when we have some changes, if we change something then all our archives links isn't going to work ( assume that we put the input to the database. ).
2. use a JavaScript to do this, i mean yes, but im not familiar with js, but i know we can search and change the links live like above. but the problem is when the user doesn't have a js on, ( mobile, or no JavaScript plugin, etc )

or maybe you have a better answer **what is the best way we implant l.php ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be one of the pros of using a function to generate links in your views:

```
<a href="<?= build_link('www.link.com'); ?>">link text</a>
```

Your `build_link()` would be like so:

```
function build_link($path)
{
   $prefix = '';
   if (preg_match('|^(https?://|www\.)', $path))
   {
     $prefix = 'http://www.oursite.php?to=';
   }
   return $prefix . $path;
}
```

This means you could even use a CDN easily amongst your links.

The easiest option is to use Javascript, but like you say is reliant on the user to have Javascript enabled browser, which is highly likey due to the advance in browser technology, even in the mobile platform. The jQuery would look like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('a').live('click', function() {
     var href = $(this).attr('href');

     if (href.match(/^(https?:\/\/|www\\.)/i))
     {
         this.href = 'http://www.oursite.php?to=' + href;
     }

       return this.href;
   });
});
```

If changing your links is not viable, i.e. you need to rewrite links that is inside a database or similar, I would look into using `DOMDocument` -- it's generally good practice to avoid messy regexes when dealing with complex structures such as HTML

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML($text);
$anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($anchors as $a) {
   $href = $a->getAttribute('href');
   if (preg_match('|^(https?://|www\.)', $href))
   {
      $a->setAttribute('href', 'http://www.oursite.php?to=' . $href);
   }
}

$newHTML = $doc->saveHTML();
```

So there are three options here:

1. Go through every part on your site that outputs links to external sites, and re-write them through a `build_link` function
2. Rewrite using the help of `DOMDocument`
3. Use Javascript

Comment: thanks!!!!, really great answer however, what do you suggest ? any cons of DOMcocument? like ram usage? it will be better if there is pro and cons of the options.

Comment: I haven't done any testing to see the performance of DOMDocument, you might want to test this yourself to see if it's too heavy or not. It probably is a bit heavy for something this simple though, so if you wanted to go down the regex route you could just do `preg_replace('|<a href="((?:https?://|www\.)[^"'>]+)|i', 'http://www.oursite.php?to=$1', $html);`

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone with using PHP to let the content of the page run through a filter that uses regex to replace the links.

Using javascript would mean that paople can turn it off. PHP ensures that all links get replaced correctly.

Just remember to make sure that any internal links (like navigation) is left untouched.

There are many types of regex that finds urls and you have to choose one that suits your needs

Edit: I would use this regex `(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)`